# Java Synchronised blocks and Anonymous classes

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

with code such as

```
synchronized (this)
{
    mTimeOutRunnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            ..some code
        }
    };
}
```

the reference assignement of the new `Runnable` class is covered by the block but will code inside run() (which is *asyncronously* called outside of the block) enter into the `synchronized` block also?

I wrapped in the sync block in the first place as this is called from a worker thread and I want to ensure the calling (main) thread has access to the `mTimeOutRunnable` object also.

Comment: Why would you be making a piece of code a thread but then subsequently require that it be synchronized, i.e. only one thread using it at a time?

Comment: sorry, the code inside the run() method here are not what is called on my worker thread - this is passed to a `Looper` (Android) which will be called on a main thread. The whole code above is on the worker thread however

Comment: (Note also that this `this` within `Runnable` will be a different `this` to the one outside. So `synchronized (this) { }` will lock on different objects and so will not work as intended.)

Comment: @Tom you mean if there were another sync block inside run which used (this) also? Looking at the answer from Keppil the sync block will have no effect inside run anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, only the assignment of your `Runnable` to `mTimeOutRunnable` is covered by the `synchronized` block, not subsequent calls to the `run()` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
mTimeOutRunnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            ..some code
        }
    };
```

is same as

```
synchronized(this){
     obj = new SomeClass();
}
```

So only the reference assignment is covered by `synchronized` block